# Get custom fields without _edit_last, _edit_lock, _wp_page_template and _visual-subtitle

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm getting custom fields using

```
<?php $meta = get_post_custom($level_2->ID); ?>
<?php foreach ( $meta as $key => $value) { ?>
    <?php echo $key.': '.$value[0].'<br />'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

and it is showing

```
_edit_last: 1<br>
_edit_lock: 1483226440:1<br>
_wp_page_template: page-services.php<br>
Body Repair: ValueBodyRepair<br>
_visual-subtitle: <br>
```

I need only 4th row `Body Repair: ValueBodyRepair<br>`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your call to [**`get_post_custom`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/) with [**`get_post_meta`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

[**`get_post_custom`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/) retrieves all the post meta fields whereas with [**`get_post_meta`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) you can specify the key of the meta field you want.

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $level_2->ID, 'Body Repair' );
```

This would give you an array with the value for the **Body Repair** meta key, To return a single value, you can use:

```
$metal key = YOUR META KEY
$meta = get_post_meta( $level_2->ID, $meta_key, true );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is showing me only `Body Repair: ValueBodyRepair<br>` . There is array and can be any other value except `Body Repair`. I shouldn't mention `Body Repair`.

Comment: Then run a loop, passing the meta key in place of 'Body Repair'

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: `<?php $meta = get_post_custom($level_2->ID); ?>
<?php foreach ( $meta as $key => $value) { ?>
  <?php if(substr($key, 0, 1) !== '_'): ?>
    <?php echo $key.': '.$value[0].'<br />'; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>` this was the solution